# google sheet custom function to max of two columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

please guide me the max function is not working, I want to take max function in desired column.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet4");
    var data = sheet.getRange("I2:J24").getValues();

    function myFunction() {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet4");
        var data = sheet.getRange("I2:J24").getValues();
        var newData = []
        for (i in data) {
            var row = data[i];
            var max = row[0]: row[1]
            newData.push([max])
            Logger.log(newData)
        }
        sheet.getRange(2, 11, 23, 1).setValues(newData)

    }
    var newData = []
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var max = row[0]: row[1]
        newData.push([max]) //the max function may not puted well
        Logger.log(newData)
    }
    sheet.getRange(2, 11, 23, 1).setValues(newData)
}
```

Comment: Why is included myFunction declaration inside a function named myFunction? What are you trying to do in `var max = row[0]: row[1]`? If you function throws an error add the textual error message. Also add some sample input data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function themaxinatwocolumnrange() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getRange(2,9,23,2);
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let max=null;
  vs.forEach(function(r){
    r.forEach(function(c){
      if(c>max) {
        max=c;
      }
    });
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(max)),"Display Results");
}
```